# Office.context.document.settings object

Tags: office-js, office-addins

Does anyone know if there is a limit on how many settings can be stored in `Office.context.document.settings` object? The documentation doesn't seem to mention anything on this matter. Also is there a way to actually see this information being saved somewhere? Where is it physically stored?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs it, I think I have found the answer to my question:

If you unzip the Word file (rename the file and give it extension .zip instead of .docx and then unzip), you'll see a folder structure inside. Go to `/word/webextensions/webextension1.xml`. This file contains everything that you've saved into `Office.context.document.settings` object. Considering that's just an xml there shouldn't be any limitations, unless Word enforces some.

If anyone knows any different, please chime in.